# how to change width of wizard buttons?

Tags: wtl

Actually, I want to increase the width of the wizard button(for eg:"Back" button).
I tried doing like this,

```
CPropertySheetWindow obj = this->GetPropertySheet();
CWindow wndObj = obj.GetDlgItem(ID_WIZBACK);

CRect backRect;
wndObj.GetWindowRect(&backRect);
ScreenToClient(backRect);
backRect.Width() += 10 ;//getting error as error C2106: '+=' : left operand must be l-value.
```

As `backRect.Width()` returns `int` this error occured.

```
BOOL bRet = wndObj.MoveWindow(&backRect);
```

After some suggestion I tried doing like this,

```
RECT backRect;
WndObj.GetClientRect(&backRect);
backRect.right += backRect.right;
InflateRect(&backRect,0,0);
InvalidateRect(&backRect);
```

But did not make any change.Still the button is of same size.

Can anyone please let me know how to change the width of the wizard buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
RECT r;
CWindow wnd(GetDlgItem(ID_WIZBACK));
wnd.GetWindowRect(&r);
r.right +=1;
wnd.MoveWindow(&r, TRUE);
```

Comment: I update my post as per your suggestion of what I tried but it did not make any change to the button size. Can you please any other suggestion. :)

Comment: A good starting point for wizards in WTL, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4979/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-VIII-Property-Sheets, why are you wanting to change the width?